# React: OnClick Cannot Set Property 'length' Of Undefined Error React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In the following code, I click on the notification icon and it calls the toggleNotificationMenu function so the viewNotifications action can fire off. However, when I do that I get the following error: "cannot read property 'length' of undefined" which is regarding the newNotifications. However, when I console.log newNotifications I can see it successfully displays an array with objects in it. viewNotifications action does successfully fire because I can see the changes made in my database. I just cannot figure out why I am getting the error.

```
class TopNavbar extends Component{
  
  static propTypes = {
    newNotifications: PropTypes.object,
    viewNotifications: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  toggleNotificationMenu = () =>{
    const {newNotifications} = this.props.notifications;
    console.log(newNotifications)
    if(newNotifications.length > 0){
      this.props.viewNotifications()
    }
  }

    render(){
        const {newNotifications} = this.props.notifications;
      return(
          <div className="TopNavbar">
            <div className="NavbarLastSection">
            <span className="TopNavbarNotification" onClick={this.toggleNotificationMenu}>
            {newNotifications.length === 0 ? <i className="TopNavbarNotificationIcon"><a><FontAwesomeIcon icon="bell"/></a></i>
            : <i className="TopNavbarNotificationIcon" style={style}><a><FontAwesomeIcon icon="bell"/></a></i>}
            {newNotifications.length === 0 ? null : <span className="NotificationBox">{newNotifications.length}</span>}
            </span>

            </div>
          </div>
      )
    }
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  notifications: state.notifications,
  error: state.error
});

const mapActionsToProps = {
  viewNotifications
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(TopNavbar);
```

Comment: First line of `toggleNotificationMenu` looks like it should be `const {newNotifications} = this.props`

Comment: `newNotifications` protype is set to `Object` and `Object` does not have length and when your component render first time it tries to render `newNotifications` value which is `undefined`

Comment: Ok I see. So how should I approach this?

Comment: @HenryWoody thank you for your response. I tried that it didnt work

Comment: you can either change `newNotifications` to `Array` or you can change your test to `newNotifications && Object.keys(newNotifications).length === 0`

Answer (score 0):

Seems your problem is the notifications prop is set to undefined when mounted. As your linking your state.notifications i would suggest to ensure that value is always an object with newNotifications in it

Comment: But when I console log newNotifications I can see an array with objects in it. I dont know why it would show as undefined

Comment: I figured it out. It was my redux action file. Made some changes and now it is working